# Keeps Crashing No Logs

Tags: node.js, linux

So my node JS script keeps crashing after a while. I'll use the "screen" command to keep the script running and then after a while E.G like a night it seems to just crash/exit the script. I'm not sure whats going on. I can't seem to push logs of whats going on as well... When I try to log with screen it just puts the outfile as empty...

Comment: maybe you could post some of your code for us to better understand the problem

Comment: and also brief info about your script.

Comment: Its just a node JS socket IO script that is connected to MySQL.

Comment: this doesn't give much to work with

Comment: I don't need help fixing the crash, I just need advice of how to debug nodejs applications.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running you application on screen, use can **nohup**, so example for running you node script would be like:

```
nohup node <your script>.js > ./outputfile.log &
```

what this will do is run your application in background and output all the console logs to a file ie. outputfile.log.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this! Thank you :)